# How do you deal with Skolem functions which escape their scope in elimination rules?

Tags: logic, type-theory, type-checking

If you have an elimination rule for tuples which introduce the left and right pair into the type checking context, what do you do if the type of one of the elements is quantified and has been Skolemized. Isn't it impossible to prevent the Skolem type from escaping its scope here?

For example the sequent:

```
            skolemize(T, (tuple A B))
               X : A, Y : B ⊢ P 
  _______________________________________________
                (X,Y) : T ⊢ P
```

Where skolemize removes prenex quantifiers, replacing universal quantifiers with unbound variables, and existential quantifiers with skolem functions, and unifies the second argument with the base type.

Since A or B may contain skolem types, where do you check for scope escape? Do you just scan the whole type checking context after the second clause?

Comment: Could you give a link to a description of the type-checking algorithm that has the problem you describe?